# Using jquery to get all checked checkboxes with a certain class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I know I can get all checked checkboxes on a page using this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
```

But I am now using this on a page that has some other checkboxes that I don't want to include.  How would I change the above code to only look at checked checkboxes that have a certain class on them?

Comment: Shall I update the title to say `class` instead of `name`?

Comment: @Russ Cam - already done

Comment: $('input[type=checkbox]`:checked`') will work too.

Answer (score 481, accepted):

`$('.theClass:checkbox:checked')` will give you all the checked checkboxes with the class `theClass`.

Comment: Nice. Also, $('.theClass:checkbox:not(:checked)') will get all the unchecked ones.

Comment: Can I do this for all checkbox with name?

Comment: How can I add another class on checked elements? I want to show border on checked input elements.

Comment: @FluffyBeing yes, to get to the input by its name you can use: `$('input[name="input_name"]:checked')` or `$('input[name="input_name"]').filter(':checked')`

Answer (score 137):

```
$('input:checkbox.class').each(function () {
       var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
  });
```

**[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/TbVkv/1/)** to demonstrate.

`:checkbox` is a selector for checkboxes (in fact, you could omit the `input` part of the selector, although I found niche cases where you would get strange results doing this in earlier versions of the library. I'm sure they are fixed in later versions).
`.class` is the selector for element class attribute containing `class`.

Comment: Jquery notes on :checkbox recommends to stick with [type="checkbox"].


$('[type="checkbox"].class')....or
$('input[type="checkbox"].class')

Comment: @TSmith do you have a reference?

Comment: I read that from here : http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/
...under "Additional Notes"

Answer (score 98):

Obligatory [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) example:

```
var checkedVals = $('.theClass:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
alert(checkedVals.join(","));
```

Comment: $('input.theClass:checked').map(function() {return this.value}).get().join(',');

Comment: @Fedir: your command gives ````on,on```` as a result ('on' for every checkbox checked)

Comment: @Jay You need to set the value attributes of your check boxes to get their value in a coma separated string

Answer (score 30):

```
$('input.yourClass:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    var sThisVal = $(this).val();
});
```

This would get all checkboxes of the class name "yourClass".  I like this example since it uses the jQuery selector *checked* instead of doing a conditional check.  Personally I would also use an array to store the value, then use them as needed, like:

```
var arr = [];
$('input.yourClass:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: If there was a need for storing the values in an array, `.map` could be a more pleasant alternative, as illustrated by karim79's answer.

Comment: thank you :) i needed to find all checked checkboxes and your answer does that.

Answer (score 14):

If you need to get the value of **all checked checkboxes** as an array:

```
let myArray = (function() {
    let a = [];
    $(".checkboxes:checked").each(function() {
        a.push(this.value);
    });
    return a;
})()
```

Answer (score 11):

```
 $('input.theclass[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
   var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
 });
```

Answer (score 9):

Simple way to get all of values into an array

```
var valores = (function () {
    var valor = [];
    $('input.className[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked)
            valor.push($(this).val());
    });
    return valor;

})();

console.log(valores);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div><input class="yourClass" type="checkbox" value="1" checked></div>
<div><input class="yourClass" type="checkbox" value="2"></div>
<div><input class="yourClass" type="checkbox" value="3" checked></div>
<div><input class="yourClass" type="checkbox" value="4"></div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".yourClass:checkbox").filter(":checked")
```

It will choose values of 1 and 3.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if it helps for your particular case, and I'm not sure if in your case, the checkboxes you want to include only are all part of a single form or div or table, but you can always select all checkboxes inside a specific element. For example:

```
<ul id="selective">
 <li><input type="checkbox" value="..." /></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" value="..." /></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" value="..." /></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" value="..." /></li>
</ul>
```

Then, using the following jQuery, it ONLY goes through the checkboxes within that UL with id="selective":

```
$('#selective input:checkbox').each(function () {
 var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 $('input.myclass[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
   var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : ""); });
```

See [jQuery class selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this

```
let values = (function() {
                let a = [];
                $(".chkboxes:checked").each(function() {
                    a.push($(this).val());
                });
                return a;
            })();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" class = "chk" value = "1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" class = "chk" value = "2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3" class = "chk" value = "3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" class = "chk" value = "4" />
<input type="button" id="demo" value = "Demo" />

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#demo").live("click", function () {
        $("input:checkbox[class=chk]:checked").each(function () {
            alert("Id: " + $(this).attr("id") + " Value: " + $(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Get-values-of-all-checked-checkboxes-by-class-name-using-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to get the ids of the checked check boxes by class name:

```
$(".yourClassName:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
     console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this has a bunch of great answers on this question already but I found this while browsing around and I find it really easy to use. Thought I'd share for anyone else looking.

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
    <!-- these will be affected by check all -->
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> Check all</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <!-- these won't be affected by check all; different field set -->
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
</fieldset>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

**Reference:**
[Easiest "Check All" with jQuery](http://briancray.com/posts/check-all-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.checkD[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $(this).val('true');
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            $(this).val('false');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: please consider adding a comment to explain your answer so that it would be easier to understand for the uninitiated

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
 <p> <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" id="fruits"  value="1" /> Apple </p>
 <p> <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" id="fruits"  value="2" /> Banana </p>
 <p> <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" id="fruits"  value="3" /> Mango </p>
 <p> <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" id="fruits"  value="4" /> Grape </p>
```

**Jquery**

> for storing the selected fruit values define array.

```
 fruitArray = [];
```

> $.each will iterate the checked check boxes and pushed into array.

```
 $.each($("input[name='fruits']:checked"), function (K, V) {    
    fruitArray.push(V.value);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='<your_name_of_selected_group_checkboxes>']:checked").val()
```

Comment: please explain what this code all about. It will help others to understand

Comment: This only gets the first value of the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checked.yourClassName").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

It's work too.

Answer (score 0):

If **only** your checkboxes have a given class name, you **don't** need to specify the `:checkbox` filter.

```js
const newArray = $('.yourClass:checked').map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get();
console.log(newArray);
```