# how to get the values of checkboxes that are checked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of dynamically populated check boxes with values. This code works but with some unnecessary stuffs like *text,free text,free text,etc with the value of my checked checkbox*

**JS:**

```
$('#save').on('click', function () {
    var val = $(':checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get()

    alert(val);
});
```

Comment: share your html also... and try `$('input:checkbox:checked')`

Comment: all the values of the checked checkbox appears but with some unnecessary text. HELP ME out!!

Comment: all the values of the checked checkbox appears but with some unnecessary text. HELP ME out!!

Comment: Refer this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450104/using-jquery-getting-all-checked-checkboxes-with-a-certain-class-name

Comment: Check what's the checkbox value using WebDeveloper or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit your selector to only checbox elements

```
//or you can use $(':checkbox:checked')
var val = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NHwpx/)