# jQuery, check if checkbox is checked with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get values of a table with jQuery. Every table row has a checkbox at the begining. How can I copy data of each row, but only if it's checked. All checkboxes and rows has the same class. Now I'm using this code:

```
var table = $("table");
    var allRows = [];
    table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
        if($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){
            var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            name = $tds.eq(2).text(),
            surname = $tds.eq(4).text();
            allRows.push(surname+";"+name+";"+"\n");
        }
    });
    allRows = allRows.join("");
```

But it's getting all the lines. How can I do this only for lines which are checked?

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now you are checking any checkbox is checked. the condition needs to be changed.

You need to check the `:checked` state of the chechbox in current row while iterating.

```
if($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length > 0){
   //your existing code
}
```

Comment: Great. Working as I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

`$('.theClass:checkbox:checked')` will give you all the checked checkboxes with the class `theClass`. 
See also [Get all checked checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450104/using-jquery-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes-with-a-certain-class-name)