# Disable inputs by class when checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have dynamically created checkboxes that share the same class:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" />
```

And have a few dropdown options that share that same class also:

```
<select class = "needToDisable">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

As these are generated dynamically, I went for this approach to check if the length of the checked checkboxes is > 0. If so disable all dropdowns with the class "needToDisable"

```
 $(".boxes").on('click',function(){
      if ($('.boxes:checked').length > 0) {
            $(".boxes").prop("disabled", true);
       } else {
         $(".boxes").prop("disabled", false);  
       }     
  });
```

I have seen a few other examples like:

[Using jquery to get all checked checkboxes with a certain class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450104/using-jquery-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes-with-a-certain-class-name)

But it says "click" is not defined, I don't think I can use in this way.

Comment: Typo - `click` instead of `'click'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use `'click'` and not `click`. Secondly, your select class is `needToDisable`, which needs to be disabled and not `.boxes`. Below is a small working demo:

```js
$(".boxes").on('click', function() {
  $(".needToDisable").prop("disabled", $('.boxes:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="boxes" />

<select class="needToDisable">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```