# Value not passing from view to controller using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to pass a value across to my controller using ajax.

ajax code as follows:

```
           var myId = $(".slectOne[checked]").attr("data-id");

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("reservation_step_1", "Home")', 
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: myId },
            });
```

controller code as follows:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult reservation_step_1(string id)
        {
            string val = id;

            return RedirectToAction("reservation_step_2", "Home", new { val = val });
        }
```

I am unsure if I am doing anything wrong but my "id" value is "null" in the controller.

Comment: What is `$(".slectOne[checked]")`?

Comment: it seems that your issue is in routing, try to change the name of the parameter to and change the httpmethod to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will definitely work.

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult reservation_step_1(string id)
    {
        string val = id;

        return RedirectToAction("reservation_step_2", "Home", new { val = val });
    }

    //my controller action name, yours is different
    public ActionResult Tut118()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut118</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#theButton").click(function () {
                //kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450104/using-jquery-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes-with-a-certain-class-name
                var myId = $('.slectOne:checkbox:checked').attr("data-id");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: '@Url.Action("reservation_step_1", "Home")',
                    data: { 'id': myId },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, anObj) {
                            $("#Asentamientos").append($('<option>').text(anObj.Text).attr('value', anObj.Value));
                        });
                    }
                });
            })

            //kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group
            // the selector will match all input controls of type :checkbox
            // and attach a click event handler
            $("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
                // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
                var $box = $(this);
                if ($box.is(":checked")) {
                    // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
                    // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
                    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
                    // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
                    // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
                    $(group).prop("checked", false);
                    $box.prop("checked", true);
                } else {
                    $box.prop("checked", false);
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>CheckBoxes</h3>
        <label>
            <input data-id="1" type="checkbox" class="slectOne" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />CheckBox1
        </label>
        <label>
            <input data-id="2" type="checkbox" class="slectOne" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />CheckBox2
        </label>
        <label>
            <input data-id="3" type="checkbox" class="slectOne" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />CheckBox3
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="theButton" value="PassData" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just gave this a try, but passes a null value. I tried to break point each line to see what is happening in the controller and found that the value is passing from view to controller, runs through "reservation_step_1" action once then values turn to null and passes null value to the receiving action. Any idea why this happens sir?

Comment: @Daniel the only thing I can say is that I know things like this are a pain.  I know my code works (I don't know why yours is not).  You can google to find solutions.

Comment: your code works just fine, i am just unsure why it is looping through the action twice, on the 1st loop i can see the values being passed but on the 2nd loop the values turn to null

Comment: it could loop twice if the .ajax code is called twice.  Like once from a trigger on button click, and another time just calling the .ajax outside of a trigger.

Comment: You're 100% right, I've commented out my "using (Html.BeginForm())"reservation_step_1", "Home")), FormMethod.Post))" and then only ran through once(No loop) but now once i click my submit button, the data passes well but my next page does not load.  It just stays on the page where i clicked the button