# $(this).prop('checked') not working for checking checkbox for Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkboxes with HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="selectMakeup" name="needsPartNumber">
```

There can be a lot of checkboxes with the same class. I want to loop through each of the checked checkboxes.

```js
$('.selectMakeup').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).html())
  console.log($(this).prop('checked'))
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    //Do Stuff
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectMakeup" name="needsPartNumber">
```

`console.log($(this).html())`

returns

`<input type="checkbox" name="needsPartNumber">`

But `console.log($(this).prop('checked'))` returns `undefined`.

Comment: The first prints `""` since the element has no `innerHTML`. The second returns `false`, as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/r64bdhqo/ - Looping through all checkboxes: `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(...)`

Comment: If the first log prints what you say it prints, it means that you are selecting its parent.

Comment: Exactly, which also explains why the prop is undefined.

Comment: This result can't be coming from the HTML and JS that you show. Post the real code.

Comment: Running the code in Edge Chromium, I see blank, then `false`...

Comment: If you have a bunch of checkboxes *inside* the element with class `selectMakeup`, you need `$('.selectMakeup :checked')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jquery to get all checked checkboxes with a certain class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450104/using-jquery-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes-with-a-certain-class-name)

Comment: What do you want to do with the checked checkboxes?

Comment: You guys are right. The code I gave turned out to be incorrect. I added the classname to the parent container by mistake in my actual code. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should return all checked checkboxes with a given class

```
$('.selectMakeup:checked').each(function() {});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a checkbox/radio option is "checked", you can use `.is()`:

```js
$('.selectMakeup').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).is(":checked"));
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      // Do something
    }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectMakeup" name="needsPartNumber">
```

-- Edit --

As the comments are suggesting, `$(this).prop("checked")` should return `true` or `false`, unless you're targeting an element via `$(this)` that isn't a radio/checkbox.

Comment: This will work, but so should the original test.

Comment: `.is()` is a selector check while `.prop()` checks its property. Both works but the later is the preferred method and the fastest.

Comment: Ah yes; just did some more tests. I got a false positive on the `undefined` result when running a test here on SO (`console.log($("input[type=radio]").prop("checked"));`). Initally got `undefined` as there were currently no rendered `radio` options, until I opened the `close` dialogue and got `true` and `false` as expected.

Comment: You should consider using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include both JavaScript and HTML in your answers -- it makes it easier to test.

Comment: With your way you have to loop over every checkbox. If you look at my answer it only returns the checked checkboxes

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, sorry. I rarely post on JS answers, so I often forget that's an option. Edited, thanks.

Comment: @BFunk That's beside the point; there might be a case where you want to do something with the unchecked ones vs the check ones. The question is just a snippet; we don't know the full context of the code. And yeah, your answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @TimLewis His post says "I want to loop through each of the checked checkboxes." So I read that as only wanting something to do with the checked ones.

Comment: @BFunk Fair observation, but again, it's beside the point. No harm in having 2 approaches.