# Get checked element by span class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using a plugin that creates a span class element based on a label I've defined in a separate javascript file.
I want to create an eventListener for when the checkbox has been checked and reference the text in the span class using jQuery.
However, I am not sure on how to reference the span class for each label class #leaflet-layerstree-header-label input.

Something like an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5450194) that adds a map function to obtain the collection.

The element for each label is referenced as such:

```
<label class="layerstree-header-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="control-layers-selector">
  <span class="layerstree-header-name">7211</span>
</label>
```

Comment: how do you want the text? lets say each time some one clicks the checkbox, you need all the texts of span in an array or something else

Comment: @Tushar I'm going to take the selections and use them as parameters in a separate request module to be called upon selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the event listener on `change` event for the checkbox and use `.siblings` to find the `span`

```js
$(".control-layers-selector").on("change", function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    console.log($(this).siblings('span').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="layerstree-header-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="control-layers-selector">
  <span class="layerstree-header-name">7211</span>
</label>

<label class="layerstree-header-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="control-layers-selector">
  <span class="layerstree-header-name">9090</span>
</label>

<label class="layerstree-header-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="control-layers-selector">
  <span class="layerstree-header-name">9090</span>
</label>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working  (i.e. no output to console with selections) - I believe I have to reference the [module](https://github.com/jjimenezshaw/Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree/blob/master/L.Control.Layers.Tree.js) itself somehow as there are multiple child layers and class inheritances from which it spans.

Comment: I cant see your full code, so you need to check your object reference yourself

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out I have to reference the container for the module in order to obtain the text for the selection. The solution that worked was as follows (with contribution from @Tushar):

```
var layerControl = L.control.layers.tree (baseMaps, overlaysTree, {
  collapsed: false
})

var htmlObject = layerControl.getContainer().querySelectorAll('input');

$(htmlObject).on("change", function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    console.log($(this).siblings('span').text());
});
```